# Create a dimensional table like those of Buckingham π theorem

Tags: amsmath, matrices

I want to create a dimensional matrix (i.e. a matrix related to the Buckingham π theorem). Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{l}
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,{\pi _1}\,\,\,\,\,\,{\pi _2}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,{\pi _3}\\
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
u\\
\rho \\
P\\
E\\
L\\
g
\end{array}\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{e_1}}\\
{{e_2}}\\
{{e_3}}\\
{{e_4}}\\
{{e_5}}\\
{{e_6}}
\end{array}} \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&{ - 1}&{ - 1}&0&1&0\\
{ - 1}&1&{ - 2}&1&2&{1/2}\\
0&1&0&0&{ - 1}&{ - 1/2}
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{e_1}}\\
{{e_2}}\\
{{e_3}}\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array}} \right]
\end{array}\]

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

I am sure that there are better ways to insert \pi_1, \pi_2 and \pi_3 above, respectively, the first, second and third column of the 6X6 matrix but I cannot figure out how. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why are all your arrays declared with 20 columns?

Comment: @Bernard I typed the system with latex. Not knowing how to add the πs above the dimensional matrix I use MathType to enter them. The resulted expression is from copy-paste from MathType to LaTeX again. I know that it is not the best way of course.

Comment: What is MathType?

Comment: @Mico https://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `nicematrix` it is nice and easy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{bNiceArray}{C}[first-col]
u & e_1\\
\rho & e_2\\
P& e_3\\
E& e_4\\
L& e_5\\
g& e_6\\
\end{bNiceArray}=
\begin{bNiceArray}{CCCCCC}[first-row]
\pi_1 & \pi_2 & \pi_3 & & & \\
1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0& - 1& - 1&0&1&0\\
 - 1&1& - 2&1&2&1/2\\
0&1&0&0& - 1& - 1/2
\end{bNiceArray}
\begin{bNiceArray}{C}
e_1\\
e_2\\
e_3\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or an attempt to make barbara beeton a bit happier. (It is possible to use `\multicolumn{1}{C}{...}` for the `\pi_i` but it does IMHO not look better.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{bNiceArray}{C}[first-col]
u & e_1\\
\rho & e_2\\
P& e_3\\
E& e_4\\
L& e_5\\
g& e_6\\
\end{bNiceArray}=
\begin{bNiceArray}{RRRRRR}[first-row]
\pi_1 & \pi_2 &\pi_3 & & & \\
1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0& - 1& - 1&0&1&0\\
 - 1&1& - 2&1&2&\tfrac{1}{2}\\
0&1&0&0& - 1& - \tfrac{1}{2}
\end{bNiceArray}
\begin{bNiceArray}{C}
e_1\\
e_2\\
e_3\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This would look even nicer if the integers were all nicely lined up with the minuses off to the left.  `\mathllap` would work for all but the leftmost column; there, some extra space would be needed to avoid a crash into the bracket.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! You are right, I tried to achieve this with right-aligned columns now.

Comment: Is there any classing known for nicematrix package?

Comment: @Dimitris I do not understand the question. What do you mean by "classing"?

Comment: Sorry I should have written clashing.

Comment: I got clash error messages. I guess they have to do with xcolor.

Comment: @Dimitris If you have a fully updated TeX installation, there should be no problem. Notice that this is a rather new package, which got even more powerful by a recent update. As for `xcolor`, you may want to pass the options *before* you load `nicematrix`, you can put something like `\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb,svgnames,dvipsnames,x11names}{xcolor}` before `\documentclass...`. where you put the options you need.

Comment: I didn't really object to the `1/2` form of the fractions, and centering them would be okay; just shift the minus off to the left.  If I wanted to be really nit-picky, I would suggest putting in an `\hphantom{-}` for the fourth column so that the columns are all nicely the same distance apart.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\[%
\makeatletter \BA@colsep=10pt \makeatother
\begin{blockarray}{cc}
  \\
\begin{block}{c@{\quad}[c]}
u & e_1\bigstrut[t] \\
\rho & e_2 \\
P & e_3 \\
E & e_4 \\
L & e_5 \\
g & e_6\bigstrut[b] \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
 =
\begin{blockarray}{*{6}{c} c}
\pi_1 & \pi_2 & \pi_3 & \pi_4 & \pi_5 & \pi_6 \\
\begin{block}{[*{6}{r}]!{\!}[c]}
  1&0&0&0&0&0 \bigstrut[t] & e_1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e_2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e_3 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 2 & \mathllap{1}/2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & \mathllap{-1}/2 \bigstrut[b] & 0 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]